# How do you the roots of functions that are not quadratics?

Tags: functions, quadratics

I was asked to consider the equation $(x-3)(x+3)^2=c$

I have been asked to find the values of C in which the equation has:

- three distinct roots only
- one real root
- a double root and a single root

I imagined the equation as $(x-3)(x+3)^2=y$ and drew this:

[image]

But that is all I have done so far, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Good so far. Now *imagine* drawing various horizontal line $y=c$ and the picture will tell you the story.

Comment: Why only for $-4\le x\le 4$?

Comment: The original part a) of the question requested it with a boundary.

Comment: Note that the question does *not* ask you to find explicit formulas for the roots in terms of $c$. That can be done, but it is hard. It just asks how many (real) roots. The answer will depend on $c$.

Comment: (Answer to a deleted comment): It is when $-32\lt c\lt 0$.

Comment: One real root would be $c>0$

Comment: A double and singe root when  $c=0$

Comment: Yes, Thank You, I understand what I did wrong because when $c=32$ there are only two roots, and $c<3$ would be incorrect as that is not in relation to y. Hence it would be as you said and not my answer of$ -32 \le c <-3$

Comment: take the derivatives of the function to find the extreme values for c (that you described in the graph). Two solutions at the extreme points, three between, and one out side. The drawing is not really needed.